# What is the opposite of an API Endpoint

Tags: api, service, client, endpoint, consumer

When talking about a service layer, I might talk about adding an Endpoint to a service. ...but when I want to talk about the corresponding consumer of that specific endpoint I would want to talk about the Client's "Invoker"?

Feels like there should be a term for this and it's been bugging me for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe thinking of an API call? Like what a user uses to get access to the endpoint?

Comment: Yeah, sure. That's a good one. A client call consumes a service endpoint. Anyone have another synonym?